# Fallo al establecer prioridades para un hilo

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, hilos

Estoy intentado establecer prioridades de hilos en Python en Windows, he visto que el GIL no permite establecer prioridades de hilos, navegando he visto que una solución pasa por usar la función de Windows `SetThreadPriority`:

- [Microsoft Docs Windows - SetThreadPriority function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreadpriority)

Sin embargo tras realizar alguna prueba no he conseguido que el hilo más prioritario se ejecute antes que el hilo menos prioritario, siempre se ejecutan a la vez.

Supuestamente incluyendo el siguiente código ya se cambiaría las prioridades:

```
import threading
import ctypes
import time

w32 = ctypes.windll.kernel32

THREAD_SET_INFORMATION = 0x20
THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE = -15
THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL = 1 
ITERATIONS=10

class DummyThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, begin, name, iterations):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.begin = begin
        self.tid = None
        self.iterations = iterations
        self.setName(name)
        self.priority = None

    def setPriority(self, priority):
        if not self.is_alive():
            print('Unable to set priority of stopped thread')

        while self.tid == None:
            pass
        print('soy {}, mi tid {}'.format(self.getName(),self.tid))
        handle = w32.OpenThread(THREAD_SET_INFORMATION, False, self.tid)
        result = w32.SetThreadPriority(handle, ctypes.c_int(priority))
        print(result)
        w32.CloseHandle(handle)
        if not result:
            print ('Failed to set priority of thread {}'.format(self.getName()))

    def run(self):
        name = self.getName()
        self.tid = w32.GetCurrentThreadId()

        self.begin.wait()
        while self.iterations:
            print ('{}, running'.format(name))
            start = time.time()
            while time.time() - start < 1:
                pass
            self.iterations -= 1
```

Esa es la clase que estoy usando para probar, de hecho la invocación a `SetThreadPriority` devuelve un valor distinto de 0, lo que supuestamente indica que efectivamente se ha cambiado correctamente la prioridad.

Pero al ejecutar las siguientes llamadas:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    start = threading.Event()

    normal = DummyThread(start, 'normal', ITERATIONS)
    high = DummyThread(start, 'high', ITERATIONS)

    normal.start()
    high.start()

    # XXX - This line adjusts priority - XXX
    normal.setPriority(THREAD_PRIORITY_IDLE)
    high.setPriority(THREAD_PRIORITY_ABOVE_NORMAL)

    # Trigger thread execution
    start.set()

    normal.join()
    high.join()
```

El resultado que obtengo es:

> soy normal, mi tid 10848
>   1
>   soy high, mi tid 12716
>   normal, running
>   high, running
>   normal, running
>   high, running
>   normal, running
>   high, running
>   normal, running
>   high, running
>   normal, running
>   high, running
>   normal, running
>   high, running
>   normal, running
>   high, running
>   normal, running
>   high, running
>   normal, running
>   high, running
>   normal, running
>   high, running

Cuando la idea es que el hilo llamado `"high"` debería de ejecutarse siempre antes que el normal, pero sin embargo no lo consigo. He revisado el modulo [Thread2](https://pypi.org/project/threading2/) y en su código aparentemente usa lo mismo.

Alguien podría darme una pista en qué está fallando.